# get wifi security type using SIOCSIWSCAN ioctl for WEP network

Tags: c, embedded-linux, wifi

I'm trying to scan the list of available networks and enumerate the security type for each SSID. I'm at a point where I can issue a SIOCSIWSCAN ioctl and parse the results. However, when I try to differentiate between a WEP network and an open network, I seem to be getting the same type of IE from the AP.

For example, I configured my Dlink DIR-655 router to be of open type vs WEP. 
Since the network is a WEP network, I look for the hex byte 0xDD to tell me that this is an IE describing a WPA/WEP/open network. For this case, I only get one byte that says 0xDD for both open and WEP networks and the corresponding IE looks the same for both:

DD 18 00 50 F2 02 01 01 83 00 03 A4 00 00 27 A4 00 00 42 43 5E 00 62 32 2F 00

Does that mean that the router doesn't populate information about open networks under the byte 0xDD and I should be looking somewhere else?

PS: I've been reverse engineering the source from iwlist to tell me how to read the IEs returned. But they only seem to be describing WPA and WPA2 networks